# How to pass dynamic html to handy-syntax-highlighter in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have implemented code highlighter in my angular 4 application. I tried to pass dynamic content to handy-syntax-highlighter. But its not working. Always displaying its first value. My html template is below.

```
<handy-syntax-highlighter [language]="'html'" [content]="this.htmlStrin"></handy-syntax-highlighter>
```

Here is the component code:

```
export class NgbdModalContent implements OnInit {
@Input() name;
@ViewChild('myForm') form; 
message :string;
htmlStrin : string;
contentObj: any;

constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, private dataService: dataService, private renderer: Renderer2, private ref:ChangeDetectorRef ) {
this.htmlStrin = '<div></div>';
}

ngOnInit() {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {}

componentList = componentList;
showCodeWindow = false;

dropdownsComponent(data){    
var content = data.html; 
for (let level1 of content) {
  this.htmlStrin = this.generateHtml(level1);
  console.log(this.htmlStrin);
  for (let level2 of level1.html) {
    this.htmlStrin +=this.generateHtml(level2);  
    if(level2.html.length> 0){
      for (let level3 of level2.html) {
        this.htmlStrin += this.generateHtml(level3);
        this.htmlStrin = this.htmlStrin.toString(); 
      }
    }        
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have implemented html code highlighter by using ng2-handy-syntax-highlighter(http://highlighter.diamondtower.pl/#/).  Its working for initial value passed to [content]. But, It was not updating the html string when i updated 'this.message' value in the dropdownsComponent method.